# Maven:Using JUnit test-help required

Tags: maven-2

In my project, I have lot of test cases.
What command can be used to selectively run one Test suite/test case?
Please help

Comment: i tried using the suggestions given below.
I find that entire test cases are getting executed instead of the one specified in the mvn command.Please help

Comment: Please provide your surfire configuration and the command you are running with the output.

Answer (score 1):

try running:

```
mvn -Dtest=<test class> test
```

More information: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: Thanks.I tried this.But testcase is not getting executed
I am just getting-
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
in pom - i have added the configuration for surefire plugin.Anything else to be done?

Comment: Would you be able to supply the pom file?  do the tests run when doing a standard "mvn install"?

Answer (score 0):

mvn test -Dtest=<test-case-name>